# How to stress test a mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database-performance, stress-testing

I like to run simulated test-clients that act as if e.g. 1000 clients execute tasks at the same time on a mongodb and see how the server stands. Together with profiling tools I like to be able to identify bottlenecks and fix them before they become a problem.

What tool would you to suggest to run simulated tests on an API Level?
What profiling tool would you suggest to identify bottlenecks, free tools are currently preferred.

Comment: I narrowed the tools down and currently I tend to user either [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) or [JMeter] (http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After quite some research I came to the point to use jmeter to do massive REST calls. That way I can create a controlled load on the database. The profiling I do with node-inspector and native mongodb profiling.

For those who like to do a more "direct" test to the DB John Page's POCDriver (simulated client): https://github.com/johnlpage/POCDriver might be interesting.

Profile visualisation (from log files) can be done with:  https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools

Hope that helps :-)